# How to use rendering variants as reusable component?

Tags: sxa, best-practices

I am looking to create reusable container section with promo rendering variants. This section should include multiple variant rendering. For example, a section with partners logo which I can reuse through out the site.

What is the best approach? Partial Design, Reusable components (rich text/HTML)??, or snippet? page content? or anything else. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Partial Designs**

You can use the `partial design` for the outer sections. like grey section containers, read section containers and black section containers. Those are constant ones. Read more at:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/page_design/page_designs

**Snippets**

Rest of the part which is static one and repeatable on multiple pages, you can create `snippets`. There are 3 configurations for the snippets. you can find here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/working_with_content/sharing_content/select_modify_and_create_associated_content.

**Unassinged Datasources**

For those `Rendering Variants` that contains the rendering parameters coming from page level, for example ( `page content component` ), you can set the data source for those components to empty and assign the parameter in the rendering variant. you can check more details on:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/the_sxa_renderings_and_rendering_variants